# How do I animate rotating 90 degrees, then rotate back to the original place?

Tags: animation, transforms

I have no clue how to do any intricate things. (like adding a texture or animating.) I want to spin a more or less rectangular object 90 degrees, twice.

Comment: You could add the keyframe (`I` when the object is selected) at the beginning and end of the animation (same rotation) then in the middle rotate it 90* and add another keyframe. The *Timeline* window is recommended to make this easier. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use basic keyframing.

Got to the start of your animation, it <kbd>I</kbd>>*Rotation* move ahead in your timeline, rotate it by 90<sup>o</sup> and <kbd>I</kbd>>*Rotation*. Move the the next location of the spin animation, and repeat the above steps.

[image]